# Angular directive for dynamically generated HTML DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Note: use of scope is not permitted in our project. We write angular1 code in angular2 way.** 
I am trying to show alert text for help icons in my project 'on click'.
I have added anchor tags dynamically to DOM as shown below (controller logic).
I am restricting the directive by CLASS... Hence, you can see the directive name in class attribute of anchor tag.

```
var helpTextData = {
          "myData" : {
            "helpIcon1" : "help text 1"
          };
    this.addHelpIconsAndText = function (sectionName) {
                for(var tagID in helpTextData[sectionName]){
                    var domNode = angular.element(document.querySelector('#'+tagID));
                    domNode.append('<a href="#" class="help-popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="help" data-content="'+helpTextData[sectionName][tagID]+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>');
                }
            };
```

The HTML

```
<div class="form-label col-md-4 col-sm-5" id="helpIcon1">
                                <label>Taxable amount :</label>
                            </div>
```

Directive

```
.directive('helpPopover', function(){
            return {
                priority: 1001,
                restrict: 'C',
                link: function(scope, element){
                          element.on('click', function () {
                              alert('Hi');
                          });
                }
          };
      });
```

This doesn't seem to generate alert on click.
However if I add an anchor tag in HTML manually as shown below, it works perfectly well.

```
<a href="#" class="help-popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="help" data-content="b">Button</a>
```

I have seen $compile, but I am not supposed to use scope variable in my project. Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Before appending DOM to element, you should compile it with `$compile` service, so that `helpPopover` directive would work

Comment: *"use of scope is not permitted"*: My most sincere condolences. Scope abuse is one thing... scope use prohibition abuse is another. Maybe we should stop breathing out carbon dioxide, because it harms the environment too? Let me put it another way: being pragmatic is good, being dogmatic probably leads to problems. Since you are in an Angular 1 environment, using the scope is unavoidable. Just make sure  that any uses are prudent. Please, do not take this rant personally, this is only my opinion on the draconian scope use prohibition directive.